# Laravel - get enum value in model eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, enums, model

I have a database with a column called 'user_types'. This column is filled with 1, 2, 3 or 4 depending on your user_type. I followed this [article](https://codebriefly.com/implementation-laravel-enum-package/) and I created my enums successfully and these can be called. However what I would like is when I call upon the User class that it would automatically replace the 1 with 'Editor' when it return the model to me. Has anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```php
public function getTypeAttribute(): string
{
    return [
        1 => 'Editor',
        2 => 'Magician',
        3 => 'Butcherer',
        4 => 'Clown'
    ][$this->user_type];
}
```

Then you can retrieve it easily:

```php
$type = $user->type;
```